# wxWidgets: Panel inside BoxSizer doesn't behaviours as expected

Tags: python, opencv, wxpython, wxwidgets

I use `Panel` to draw images from `OpenCV`, but it seems this `panel` cannot be placed into `BoxSizer`. I tried to do

```
vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
panel.SetSizer(vbox)
vbox.Add(wx.Button(panel, label='aaa', size=(70, 30)))
vbox.Add(wx.Button(panel, label='aaa', size=(70, 30)))
vbox.Add(wx.Button(panel, label='aaa', size=(70, 30)))
vbox.Add(OpenCVCanvas(self), border=10)
```

The buttons layout correctly, but the panel is always placed at the left top corner. Is there anything I did wrong?

Code for panel:

```
class OpenCVCanvas(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.onPaint)
        self.bmp = None

    def updateImage(self, frame):
        if self.bmp is None:
            height, width = frame.shape[:2]
            self.SetSize((width, height))
            self.bmp = wx.BitmapFromBuffer(width, height, frame)
        self.bmp.CopyFromBuffer(frame)
        self.Refresh()

    def onPaint(self, evt):
        if self.bmp is not None:
            dc = wx.BufferedPaintDC(self)
            dc.DrawBitmap(self.bmp, 0, 0)
```

Comment: You should really formulate your question better. You're talking about panel, while having a `panel` variable but give the declaration of `OpenCVCanvas`

Comment: While adding panel to boxer ,try giving parameters to fit to sizers, in C++ i would give like wxEXPAND

Comment: @catalin do you think renaming `OpenCVCanvas` to something like `MyPanel` is better?

Answer (score 2):

This is likely the source of the problem:

> vbox.Add(OpenCVCanvas(self), border=10)

You are creating buttons that are children of `panel` and addign them to the sizer which is set to the the `panel`'s sizer, but the `OpenCVCanvas` is using `self` as its parent which I assume is the parent of `panel` which means that the `OpenCVCanvas` is a sibling of `panel`, not its child.  The sizer can not manage the size and layout of an item that is not a child of the window the sizer is assigned to.

Comment: I followed your advice and change the parent of `OpenCVCanvas` to `self.panel`, but it still now working...